# Colour Calibration Hardware Compatible with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, screen, monitor, thinkpad, color-management

I have a Thinkpad W520 and it has a Pantone colour calibrator.I looked it up here and in Google Search but as it seems the gnome colour manager can't use it as calibrating device at all(maybe there is no driver at all to do so,but anyway this is not the key issue). So I was wondering if there is any other colour calibrating hardware(from Pantone or any other decent company) which will be compatible with Ubuntu.There is I am asking this is because I have noticed that in Windows 7 where the Pantone colour calibrator of my laptop works,the eye strain is not happening so often it when it happens it usually is noticeable after a 2-3 hours where in Ubuntu I get it usually after 40 minutes of continuous use.

If by the way there is a way to make Ubuntu to use the colour of the laptop if you do not mind please explain to avoid any additional expenses from the purchase of a new colour calibration hardware.

Comment: Have you looked at http://snart.com/color-calibrating-with-ubuntu-11-10/? It may be a simple matter of getting the updated software. I'm not sure if you mean your laptop has a calibrator built-in, or you already have a separate hardware module.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "....get the updated software."?I think gnome color calibration software is in the official repos of 12.04.So it updates automatically via the Updater.What I mean is that I already have a built-in color calibrator in my laptop,but it doesn't work with Ubuntu 12.04.So I was wondering if there is any other compatible hardware with Ubuntu 12.04.Unless,there is a way which I haven't found out to make the built-in calibrator work with 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux supported hardware, there's the [ColorHug](http://www.hughski.com/), which was created by Richard Hughes, the principal developer of GNOME Color Manager. I have one, and can recommend it. It comes with a liveCD you can use to calibrate almost any x86-based system; I've used it on Macs, too.

Alternatively, you could search your Windows partition and see where the Pantone calibrator has put the ICC file for your display. If it uses a standard file, it should be usable with Ubuntu. Don't forget that some applications — notably Firefox (for details, fiddle about with the settings described [here](http://www.metalvortex.com/blog/2012/07/12/979.html)) — use their own colour management framework.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation.I have to say that ColorHug is the best color calibrator I have ever used.And compared to others is very cheap.For the other users who might have question,I can confirm that ColorHug is the a very good solution for color calinration under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem.The developers/developer who are/is making the [dispcalGUI](http://dispcalgui.hoech.net/) they mention which devices are supported by their software.You can see it to their website [HERE](http://dispcalgui.hoech.net/#instruments)

So I guess I will go for X-Rite i1 Display Pro.I would like to go for a Huey Pro,but I looked it up on the web and there were people telling that Pantone is not supporting any more that specific device and whoever has a newer/more modern screen (either laptop screen or a normal PC monitor or MAC monitor) might not be able to make it work properly with them and make the colors look nothing,but normal.